# Debugging not working in unit test in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

I have a problem in android studio in debug mode. When I debug the normal code, it's working fine and it stoping in the points. When I tried to debug in test case it's not working i.e. it not stoping the points of line. What is the reasons behind this ?

```
Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639, built on May 12, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 13.4.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 16
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    gradle.version.catalogs.dynamic.support=true

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    idea.plugin.protoeditor (222.4459.16)
```

**UPDATE**

This is sample [project](https://github.com/vivek-modi/Debug-unit-test) and [video](https://youtu.be/u9SFdb1mbvU). In the video you can see I made a 2 break points and tried to run my test case in my debug mode. The break point is not stoped and my unit test runs successfully.

Comment: Please show the code for an example test as well as the code which is being tested.

Comment: Are you sure that the test will execute the code where the breakpoint is set?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, yes I added my project and video link of the problem. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding? Sometimes the app doesn't carry the latest version of the source code.

Comment: Your breakpoint is in the middle of an `if` expression. What happens if you put the breakpoint on the `return` instead?

Comment: My guess here is that Android Studio will only recognize breeakpoints on individual statements, but won't break in the middle of an expression. So this has as much to do with understanding Kotlin syntax and semantics as it does with Android Studio. In this case, it is important to note that Kotlin has an `if` **expression** which is different from the `if` statement we all learned in Java.

Comment: The example which i used is very small. I was tried even bigger function and every line of code but still not working. If you need the code and video. I can show you